# Sinusoidal Projection and ArcInfo Sphere Datum Woes

Tags: coordinate-system

I am using published forest loss data (found here: http://glad.geog.umd.edu/indonesia/data2014/index.html) that uses the ArcInfo Sphere datum with a sinusoidal projection. I am seeking to transform a DEM (I've tried Aster and SRTM), or any raster in GCS_WGS_194, really, into this datum/projection. However, when I do so (using a geocentric transformation with parameters set to "0") the images don't align. I've completed the transformations in both Arc and in ERDAS, to no avail.

Comment: What happens if you just display the two datasets in ArcMap, and don't set a transformation at all? If they do align, set the data frame to the coordinate system you want the data to be in, and export it by right-clicking the layer and select data, export data. If you're trying to automate conversion, instead use a custom transformation but with longitude rotation as the method (or Null depending on the version you have).

Comment: Apologies for losing track of this thread. Indeed, I did end up using the "on the fly" projection, after checking the quality of the alignment.